Unhandled exception: When importing my Deep learning python code on C#
Heads Up:

I am using Visual Studio 2022
My python code consists of a machine learning model which is getting trained. So it has python libraries imported within the Python code (Ex: Import numpy as np. Import TensorFlow) etc.
I am using Python version 3.7 and have installed all the dependencies using Anaconda environment.
I have installed IronPython in Visual Studio

Now, my question is as follows:
I need to import my Python code into C# or Visual Basic environment using Visual Studio. During this process, I am facing issues of unhandled exception - Microsoft.Scripting.SyntaxErrorException: 'invalid syntax'.
I am sure that the error is because of the initial imports inside my python script. Such as:
import os
import keras

My current basic VB .NET code is as follows:
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim oEngine As Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptEngine = Python.CreateEngine()
        oEngine.CreateScope()

        ' Set Python path
        oEngine.SetSearchPaths(New String() {"C:\Users\Anaconda3\envs\Project_Name\Lib"})

        Dim oScope As Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptScope = oEngine.CreateScope

        oEngine.ExecuteFile("Path_to_my_python_script.py", oScope)
        Dim autoencoderTrainer = oScope.GetVariable("AutoencoderTrainer")
        ' Instantiate the AutoencoderTrainer class
        ' Instantiate the AutoencoderTrainer class with arguments
        Dim pathData As String = "Path_to_the_data_folder"
        Dim trainer = oEngine.Operations.CreateInstance(autoencoderTrainer, pathData)
        ' Call the train_autoencoder() function
        Dim trainedModel = trainer.train_autoencoder()

    End Sub
End Class

Solution tried by me:

Tried to specify the lib folder of my python environment on Visual Studio.
oEngine.SetSearchPaths(New String() {"C:\Users\Anaconda3\envs\Project_Name\Lib"})

Is there a way, where I can resolve this issue? Do I need to install all dependencies again on Iron Python or is there a way where I can set a path, where all my installations are present?
Basically, I need to somehow run my Python script inside my C# environment.

"need to somehow run my Python script inside my C# environment." - you don't seem to have a "C# Environment" ??

You have a Anaconda3 user? Or rather a Anaconda3 folder in your user directory? Then your username is missing in the path.

^^ Do you want to stick to VB.NET (which I would not recommend) - then change the tag or do you want to switch to C#, in which case I'd first go and make a new C# project and try again?

Hi @fildor
I need to run either in VB .NET or C# environment.
As, I told, I am facing issues when I try to import libraries from my python file.
In case, you need to replicate the environment, try to create a test.py file and add two lines of code.
Import os
Import keras
Now, if possible, can you run this python script on VB or C#, without error?
Any leads will be really helful. Thanks for your comment!
